# Problems with UIMA Ruta Plugin - Unhandled event loop exception

Tags: eclipse-plugin, uima, ruta

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gChA2.png)

I get Unhandled event loop exception every time after trying to run a new script in the UIMA Ruta Eclipse plugin, when I test a document that were processed before with another descriptor.

The only solution to that, that worked, was to rename the test documents, so they could be processed again. (not handy at all)

The same behaviour was also - when a new rule is defined, probably with some bugs in it (I am just trying out the Ruta for the first time), than all crashes again and it is not possible to work with the plugin until the documents are replaced (renamed).

When I test the same grammar script in Java without Ruta workbench it does its job.

I use UIMA Ruta 2.5.0 and Eclipse Mars.2.

What can I do to make the Workbench function normally?

It seemed to help - the change of preferences as suggested from Peter in comments. But still when I change even a String in grammar I get exceptions and failures in the Workbench and it shows the old results (from previous version of the grammar). Here is the stacktrace:

[stacktrace from error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6GNT.png)

Comment: Where is this exception reported (console, error log)? Is there a stacktrace? What kind of project do you use? A Simple ruta project with input folder?

Comment: @Peter Kluegl The exception comes in Error log of the UIMA Ruta View in Eclipse. I tried the test Ruta Project with uima.ruta.example and input folder. I added some new packages and scripts to that first project. Actually there is a problem with viewing the output file almost every time after each processing, when I change something. The new error is: Unable to create part. Editor could not be initialized. Again: in Java the grammar functions well.

Comment: The documents in the input folder are not text file but CAS files, right? Which serialization format do they have? xmi?

Comment: The documents in input are .txt, as the example docs. Shouldn't they?

Comment: Txt files are fine. I am just trying to understand to problem. Is there more text in the error message? Is there additional text in the CAS Editor? Can deactivate the preference "UIMA Cas Editor" -> "Cas Editor Ide" -> "Use the previously selected..." and activate "UIMA Cas Editor" -> "Annotation Editor" -> "Load CAS leniently..."?

Comment: It seemed to help - the change of preferences.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by a change of type system causing an exception that UIMA wants to deserialize annotation of type that are not defined in the type system.

You can either deactivate the preference "UIMA Cas Editor" -> "Cas Editor Ide" -> "Use the previously selected..." and select a new type system.

Or you can activate the preference "UIMA Cas Editor" -> "Annotation Editor" -> "Load CAS leniently..." in order to ignore these annotations. Please mind that they will be gone if the file is saved.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: This adjustment makes the workbench do its work somehow. But the many many errors, which appear after each processing of grammar or after each click into the text field - while testing or generating a perspective - they remain. I have to click to OK to some error message after almost each operation and this not convenient for a work. The examples of the error messages are in my first post.

Comment: Yes, this error is very annyoing. It should already be fixed and be part of the next release. I assume that you use Eclipse Neon? As a workaround, you could probably close the views (Tru Positives, False Positives, False Negatives)